# How to not redirect a single folder on a website....in htacess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I have my website in a subfolder from the main root.

www.domain.com  ---redirects to--->   www.domain.com/Folder1/

using:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} domain.com [OR]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} www.domain.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.com/Folder1/ [R=301]
```

this is working fine...
I also have a administrative WebApp located on Folder2.  Folder2 users will always enter the direct URL to Folder2.

http://www.domain.com/Folder2/Version1/

It is at the same structure level as Folder1.

Problem is that when I try to access my webapp, its not working anymore and redirecting it to the Folder1 website.

**Question:**  What htaccess code do I need to add to keep my webapp (folder2) working by not redirecting it to Folder1, while still making all regular users go to Folder1.

**Customer facing Website:**  www.domain.com/Folder1/

**Internal Admin Website:**     www.domain.com/Folder2/Version1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Folder2 you should add the following line to .htaccess

```
RewriteRule .* - [L]
```

This rewrite rule takes precedence over the .htaccess in the parent directory.